# How to access and modified UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I add UINavigationBar via Library to view.But I don't know how to change this UINavigationBar from my ViewController.m. My view includes also TableView.This view have to be called from default application view.

In viewController.m,I added the following code but I can't change NavigationBar properties.

self.navigationItem.title=@"List";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title=@"Back";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's different UINavigationBar and UINavigationItem..
In the .h file use:

```
UINavigationItem *item;
```

And in the .m file:

```
item.title = @"List";
```

Don't forget to connect UINavigationItem with the "item" in the XIB file
Double click UINavigationBar and you will get UINavigationItem...
Good luck

Comment: Thank @Alex Moskalev. Your post is useful for me.But I got another problem.I want to add  backbuttonitem to this UINavigationItem

Answer (score 1):

`[UIViewController navigationItem]` is defined in the category `UINavigationControllerItem` of `UIViewController` in the UINavigationController.h, so you can access it like this:

```
UINavigationItem* navigationItem = viewController.navigationItem;
```

Most likely this is what you need. However, it you really need to access `navigationBar`, access it this way:

```
UINavigationBar* navigationBar = viewController.navigationController.navigationBar;
```